# adding array into multiple column in python

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I have an array that I want to append as multiple columns
[what I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71WtY.png)

[what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ryyT.png)

```
pages = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
with open(nlnewsdata, 'a',newline='') as nlnews:
wr = csv.writer(nlnews, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
wr.writerow(['Daily Journal (Park Hills, MO)',"Jan","2003",result,pages])
```

now the output Im expecting is like this

Daily Journal (Park Hills, MO),   Jan  ,   2003,     6, 1,2,3,4,5,6

what Im getting is

Daily Journal (Park Hills, MO), Jan,2003,6,1 2 3 4 5 6

I want to split the array into different columns not all the pages in a single column
I have tried **np.savetext** and **pages.tofile** but the thing is I am adding some data row by row and on the same run I want this array to split across multiple columns too.

Comment: Could you give a screenshot of what you are getting? I couldn't reproduce what you paste here.

Comment: ok let me do that

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `*` to unpack the list

```py
wr.writerow(['Daily Journal (Park Hills, MO)',"Jan","2003",result,*pages])
```

Comment: simply brilliant thousands of likes

Comment: in case if the numbers are two digit it will sort of break it down too that I dont want to do

Comment: @snoozy Don't understand, give some examples?

Comment: e.g. if the pages are upto 20 and the list is like this [1,2,3,4,5,6....11,12,13,14....20] the two-digit numbers are splitting into different columns instead of one column like 11 should be 11 but it is saving like 1,1. I have tested the code by just using the list but that won't split but 2 digit numbers from the website solits.

Comment: @snoozy I think it couldn't be this case, give a screenshot what it is like.